# MySQL TimeZone Randomly Resets

Tags: mysql

I am running MySql version 8 and randomly it seems the timezone gets reset. I have run the following command : SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+6:00';

This fixes the issue and then randomly a few weeks later we get the error again.
"the server time zone value 'coordinated universal time' is unrecognized"

Any idea how I can make this setting stay?

Comment: Something is trying to set that timezone. I don't think we can help you find out what that is from here. Can you turn up logging on your server instance? Go through the software that talks to your server?

Comment: Interesting. There is only one application that communicates with this db and its a very basic java app.
Are you suggesting something in the OS may be trying to reset it?

Comment: More likely you misunderstood something in the app, or you're mistaken that only one application uses this DB ;) Either way, I can assure you that MySQL does not randomly break its own timezone setting every few weeks.

Comment: I hear ya, but when I say basic, I mean basic! I know the code well and its just doing some standard queries. This started happening after we upgraded to version 8 of mysql. This never happened prior to that. I understand I can update the connection string to fix this but I would like to understand why this is happening and if there are other options.